# GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(ViewDeckPages.this,1,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false); not working

Tags: java, android

I have implemented `GridLayoutManager` to scroll horizontally with `RecyclerView`.

I am querying the database and getting 3 results which are displayed properly by `GridLayoutmanager` and `RecyclerView` (one result per page).

Problem:

1) The problem is when I am scrolling from the first page to the next page the scrolling is not working properly.

2) I need to press the end of the mobile screen and scroll it and the next page comes and stuck in middle. also sometimes scroll not works.

I am new to this concept please help on above

```java
private RecyclerView pagetlist;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private static final String TAG = "ListPages";
List<String> listPagesData;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_deck_pages);

    mDatabaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    mToolbar=findViewById(R.id.view_deck_pages_toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("View Decks");

    pagetlist=findViewById(R.id.all_user_pages_list);
    pagetlist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    pagetlist.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=
        new GridLayoutManager(ViewDeckPages.this,1,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    pagetlist.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

I want to scroll smoothly for now it gets stuck in between.

Comment: Can you post your xml file?

Comment: thanks cryille... i have resolved this issue.